# Email confirmation account sendgrid

Tags: heroku, sendgrid, sendgrid-rails

i get  an **addon sendgrid** for my app of **heroku,** but when i want go to my account of sendgrid,i need send email for the confirmation and heroku choose automatically an Heroku email example: **appXXSADAS0878@heroku.com**, i confirm this email, the same way how say the tutorial but i not have access to this, then my sendgrid account never is authenticated and after of 10 minutes waiting the confirmation the account is banned.anyone can help me with this?, i am deploying a rails app.

this tutorial that i follow for the add on sendgrid
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why would Heroku tell SendGrid to send the confirmation email to a `@heroku.com` email address.

However, consider using SendGrid without the Heroku add-on (you do not need SendGrid's add-on installed on Heroku, to send emails from your application).